# OS reinstallation after motherboard replacement

Tags: windows-7, cpu, motherboard, reinstall

I am thinking of buying a new processor ( a Pentium g3250) and a compatible mobo (ASRock Intel H81M) to go with it. They will be replacing an old Celeron processor on a g31 mobo.

My question is:

Will my current OS (Windows 7) stop working? If so, what should I do to get it working again?

PS: I am ready for a full fresh install.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't indicate if you have an OEM license or a Retail license.  Since you plan to reinstall Windows 7, any comments I have with regard to that, does not really apply.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases it will automatically repair the installation and boot successfully on the new motherboard without you needing to do anything. I successfully moved a Windows 7 installation from a Lenovo SFF machine to an HP SFF machine and had no issues. You may have to reactivate Windows.